# Python 7zip (py7zr) not registering file type

Tags: python, 7zip

I have a script to extract all the contents of an .exe file however, the `register_archive_format` and `register_unpack_format` functions don't seem to work as expected. Here's a short version of my script:

```
import os
import re
import py7zr
import wget
import shutil
import zipfile

versions = ["1.10", "2.0", "2.1pre"]
shutil.register_archive_format('exe', py7zr.pack_7zarchive, description="exe archive")
shutil.register_unpack_format('exe', ['.exe'], py7zr.unpack_7zarchive)
print("Supported formats:")
formats = shutil.get_unpack_formats()
print(formats, "\n")

with py7zr.SevenZipFile(f"C:/Users/Me/Documents/Builds/{version}/{filePath}", 'r') as zip_ref:
                    folderName = re.search("^([^_]+)(-installer)([^.]*)", fileNameOnly)
                    folderName = folderName[1] + folderName[3]
                    #zip_ref.extractall(f"C:/Users/Me/Documents/Builds/{version}/{folderName}")
                    shutil.unpack_archive(zip_ref, f"C:/Users/Me/Documents/Builds/{version}/{folderName}")
```

The code prints the list of supported formats from `shutil.get_unpack_formats()` and seems to correctly show the exe file registered. But when the code reaches the `shutil.unpack_archive()` function it throws `py7zr.exceptions.Bad7zFile: not a 7z file`.

Is there a step I'm missing in order to extract from an exe file? I know I can extract from the exe as I do that manually through the context menu of the exe file.

Answer (score 0):

py7zr support only a 7z file that has an extension foo.7z (it is not mandatory) and the binary should be started with '7z' magic keyword.
You may want to extract a self extracting archive (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) which will start a magic bytes which indicate it as executable. It is not supported by the tool.

That is why py7zr say it is not a (plain) 7z file.

Please see details at https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py7zr.html